# Visual Studio 2008, Local Database, cannot modify custom table view

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I just installed Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 on my machine - in that order.

I note that VS insisted on installing SQL Server 2005 Express in order to be able to create a local database in by web projects.

In any case, whenever I add a local database and go to create a diagram, I can't seem to modify the `Custom` table view.

For example, I like to see the column name, data type, nullable and default value columns.

Whenever I click `"Table View" - "Modify Custom"`, nothing happens!

Strangely, this action works fine in SQL Server 2008.

Has anyone else ever encountered this - and (hopefully) found a solution?

Comment: Are you running SP1 of VS2008 and/or SQL Server?

Comment: Yes - Visual Studio 2008 (ver 9.0.30729.1 SP) and I assume on SQL Server 2008.  After installing I used Windows Update until there was nothing left to download.

Comment: Do you have administrator priviliges?